# Rotating Entire SKView Around Origin

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to rotate my entire SKView according to my userAcceleration around the origin. While it is very easy to rotate individual sprites. I am having trouble rotating the entire scene and all the children around the origin. Hope that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: In the end I was able to solve this by embedding the other nodes into a blank parent node I called the background. And then rotating that background parent node.

Comment: Rotate a SKView or the scene is a bad idea, as you said, is better to create a "worldNode" as Apple documents recommended

Comment: Thanks Simone. It ultimately proved most efficient to create a camera, attach that to the origin and rotate the camera accordingly.

Comment: Yes, camera is a good solution, but worldNode is allways racommended

Comment: @SimonePistecchia that is the answer, post it and I will give you an upvote

Answer (score 1):

Rotate a SKView or the scene is a bad idea, as you said, is better to create a "worldNode" as Apple documents recommended.
So in all your game, create a worlNodeLayer and a Camera to perform in the correct way your game